# Парсер информации, заключающейся в определенных тегах

Tags: php

Нужен парсер на PHP. Нужно, чтобы он заходил по заданому в переменной url, затем парсил информацию из определенных тегов.

Допустим, url у нас http://site.ru/, а информацию нужно спарсить из тегов `<infa>здесь информация</infa>`, эту спарсеную информацию он заносит в определенную `$a`, на этом вся работа оканчивается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А где же ваши наработки? Это Вам не сайт фриланса. Смотрите функции:
`preg_match, file_get_contents`.

Comment: Так curl тем более не на всех хостингах стоит. А file_get_contents я видел один раз, что он запрещён из 8 хостингов, как минимум. И тогда очень сильно удивился. Но там ещё и curl не было, пришлось просить чтобы либо разрешили file_get_contents, либо curl поставили.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` - на большенстве хостингах закрыто вроде) надо глядеть в сторону Библиотеки cURL)